# How to get both request for users mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: Hi Please click this link]

I have attached db structured image. I want get join group requests. When someone click join group notification should got to group owner, and if group owner add some user to group then notification should go to user whom he trying to add. Please help me with this. ParentId is group owner id

Comment: So what do you mean. I have to pay to get answer? I explained what I am trying to achieve. And I don’t think its expected solution

Comment: You don't have to pay, you just have to show some effort on your part. You're a programmer, aren't you? That means you should be able to try to solve it yourself. If it doesn't work, show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I am frontend dev. I know mysql but not that much deep. So I thought i should put it here

Comment: Even as a front end dev, if someone gave you this spec you couldn't implement it. Show some structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE {x}`, What do you mean `get join requests`, what would an output be?  How do you reach a group owner? Be specific.